# Merging two dataframes - UPSERT in python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, dataframe

Insert or update in pandas dataframe

I want to merge storage_df and processed_df like given below. Suppose phone is the primary key:
1. If value exists then the fields (and create remaining columns, like gender in the below example)
2. If value doesn't exists then insert that value in final dataframe, like 382837371 in the example

Note that column can keeps on increasing as we process more information. However there is a limit of 32 columns till which processed_df/storage_df would increase

```
storage_df
________________________
Phone       Name
918348483   Sumit
874647474   Saurabh
238362633   NA
```

```
Processed_df
_______________________________
Phone       Name    Gender
874647474   Saurabh Male
238362633   NA  Female
382837371   NA  Male
```

```
final_df
_______________________________

Phone       Name    Gender
918348483   Sumit   NA
874647474   Saurabh Male
238362633   NA  Female
382837371   NA  Male
```

To do this I used combine_first of pandas:

```
final_df = processed_df.set_index('phone').combine_first(storage_df.set_index('phone'))
```

But as the size of dataframe increases the system runs out of memory (16Gb memory and failed to combine shape (88488, 6) and shape (7307, 8)

Possibility to use sqlite to store two dataframes in sql and then use UPSERT. Can you guide me on the syntax to do that? Though I would really like to do it in memory than in database.

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5364, in combine_first
    return self.combine(other, combiner, overwrite=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5229, in combine
    this, other = self.align(other, copy=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3792, in align
    broadcast_axis=broadcast_axis)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8423, in align
    fill_axis=fill_axis)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8459, in _align_frame
    allow_dups=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4490, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1220, in reindex_indexer
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 929, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1899, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 3146, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = np.vstack([b.values for b in blocks])
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 283, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Is it possible to not have 'Name' in storage_df, but have it in Processed_df for a specific phone number?

Comment: Yes.. but phone will always be there in both the dataframes. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try pandas outer join.

```
final_df = storage_df.merge(processed_df, on='Phone', how='outer', suffixes=('', '_y'))

final_df.drop(list(final_df.filter(regex=r'.*_y$').columns), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

1. Join Dataframe(s)
2. Drop extra column from merge

Comment: This could work, if you could tell me a generic way of doing it (Like i dont know if the column name is Name or something else). If you know something about str.endwith(_y) or something similar then hopefully I am done,

Comment: @SumitSingh this should solve your problem for the above-mentioned use case

Comment: ``` storage_df = process_storage_df(storage_df, processed_df, file)
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite doesn't support full outer joins to make this trivial, but you can get similar results with some work. Consider something like

```sql
SELECT s.phone, s.name, ifnull(p.gender, 'NA') AS Gender
FROM storage_df AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN processed_df AS p ON s.phone = p.phone
UNION
SELECT phone, name, gender FROM processed_df
```

```
Phone       Name        Gender    
----------  ----------  ----------
238362633   NA          Female    
382837371   NA          Male      
874647474   Saurabh     Male      
918348483   Sumit       NA
```

Comment: As at the time of doing this I actually do not know if the column in Gender, can it be more generic (probably a python example would help)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is delete the duplicate column first and do an outer join.

```
# as mentioned you don't need this.
processed_df.drop('Name', axis=1, inplace=True)

# now do an outer join
storage_df.merge(processed_df, on='Phone', how='outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `Phone` as the index for the two dataframes as they as the primary key as you say and then use `pandas.concat`.

While doing that remove the common columns from the other dataframe else they will repeat in the resulting dataframe.

```
>>> df1.set_index('Phone', inplace=True)
>>> df2.set_index('Phone', inplace=True)
>>> other_cols = set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns)
>>> df = pd.concat([df1, df2[other_cols]], axis=1)
>>> df
              Name  Gender
Phone                     
238362633      NaN  Female
382837371      NaN    Male
874647474  Saurabh    Male
918348483    Sumit     NaN
```